# How do I delete a question?

Tags: support

How do I delete this question: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65754/adb-push-command-gone-very-wrong-d-cant-revert

Answer (score 4):

You can always use the "delete" link below your question text:

> [image: question links]

Comment: Well, that's not strictly true. If a question has upvoted answers the OP can't delete it.